# Combine multiple ObservableCollections as one single ObservableCollection in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

Should be simple but couldn't hit the right blog post explaining the solution to this problem.

So the scenario is that there is one object `RuleApp` having different nested Rule collections (of type `ObservableCollection`) at any N level deep and I only want to combine those specific collections pieces together to bind it on Hierarchal `TreeView` in WPF.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Rules}" 
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource RuleTemplateSelector}">
</TreeView>
```

Life is good if it is just one ObservableCollection for binding but now the challenge is any changes to underlying distinct collections should be reflected instantly on the `TreeView` without the need to rebind the collections again, because of its costly operation and not very elegant.

From the implementation perspective, I have a method say `GetRules` returning `IEnumerable<Rule>` in which I am yielding the resultant collections and inside ViewModel newing it to `ObservableCollection<Rule>` which is causing a rebind upon identifying any change (which is undesirable). Now obviously I know the issue here that ObservableCollection is keeping a copy and not keeping itself sync with the underlying collection.

```
RuleApp obj;
// ...
Rules = new ObservableCollection<Rule>(obj.GetRules());
```

As per my research, `CompositeCollection` is a useful class to combine different collection to bind and stay synced but the problem is nested collections which could vary and are not fixed.

Any useful suggestion to coup with this problem?

Comment: Appreciate explaining the reason for the negative vote in order to improve the question if it is missing anything.

Comment: So you have hierarchy of ObservableCollections and want them to be synchronized with "underlying" collections? If that's the case - how do you identify when "underlying" collection changes?

Comment: Raising a domain event as soon as any change happens in the underlying collections, that mechanism is already in place.

Comment: And that domain event allows you to identify which collection exactly has changed in that hierarchy? Because the only reasonable way I think is to manually compare your ObservableCollection with underlying one and add\remove items as necessary.

Comment: Don't you think its inelegant to compare collections? There must be some way to handle such cases/scenarios gracefully.

Comment: In your case you have some underlying collection, changes to which are not tracked using "standard" ways (`INotifyCollectionChanged` interface). You may consider implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` on that underlying collection itself and get rid of intermediate `ObservableCollection`. But if that's not appropriate - not sure what else can be done. You have to convert your "domain" change notification event to the way WPF understands. Also, if you event is granular enough (says what item was added\removed) - you won't need to compare collections.